# Textview Marquee not scrolling in lollipop version

Tags: java, android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, marquee

I have  marquee for text view and its scrolling in pre-lollipop versions    smoothly. But cannot work in lollipop versions and above . Please help me on this.

Following are code for XML.

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="#00AEEF"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:freezesText="true"
   />
```

Comment: Have you added "txtView.setSelected(true);" in your code ?

Comment: @sunilsunny: Yes i added .. text marquee in pre lollipop versions but not in lollipop and above .. but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a MyTextView extends TextView
then override isFocus()

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    if (focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    if (focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    //always focus  
    return true;
}
}
```

then use

```
  <common.widget.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_autoplay"
    android:background="#CDC9C4"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="marqueemarqueemarqueemarqueemarqueemarquee……………………"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp" />
```

Comment: I changed my code to urs code but not scrolling my text.. my text come from database and textview show only first line of text after that three dots not showing all data and scrolling text.. Please help me

Comment: i used u r link .. and it works like charm thanks for that.  but it show one line 3 times and after that second line 3 times and all.. but i want to  show first line 1 time and after seond line 1 time and again first line , second line .. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

`scrollbars = "horizontal"` for horizontal,`scrollbars = "vertical"` for vertical.

Try with following code

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "horizontal"
```

Comment: Thanks .  i will try.